# get the first of duplicates in array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, unique

I have the following data structure that i receive from the api:

```
[
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-01',
  },
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-02',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-03',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
  {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
 {
    id: '12002812',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
   {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-08',
  },
]
```

The perfect outcome of cleaning the code would be this result, basically returning only the first found id:

```
[
      {
        id: '10000844',
        text_id: '10000844-01',
      },
      {
        id: '12000844',
        text_id: '12000844-03',
      },
      {
        id: '12000814',
        text_id: '12000844-07',
      },
     {
        id: '12002812',
        text_id: '12000844-07',
      },
    ]
```

But currently it only returns the last found duplicate in a unique array, with the current code:

```
let uniqueArray = [...new Map(data.map(item =>
    [item.id, item])).values()];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects

Comment: I think you need to group and keep an array of `text_ids`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Object.values()` and `reduce()` same as :

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-01',
  },
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-02',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-03',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
  {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
 {
    id: '12002812',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
   {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-08',
  },
]

const result = Object.values(
  data.reduce((res, {id, text_id}) => {
    res[id] ??= {id, text_id}
    return res
  }, {})
)
console.log(result)
```

**Update** with `??=`  [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

The logical nullish assignment `(x ??= y)` operator only assigns `if x is nullish (null or undefined)`.

Comment: You may want to explain what `??=` does.

Comment: You can check it in : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Comment: :) _I_ know what it means but it's a relatively new feature so might be confusing. +1 for updating your answer.

Comment: I understood what you meant so I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-01',
  },
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-02',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-03',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
  {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
 {
    id: '12002812',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
   {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-08',
  },
];
const unique = [];
const visited = new Set();
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
  if(!visited.has(arr[i].id)){
    unique.push(arr[i]);
    visited.add(arr[i].id);
  }
}

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: "You can do it like this" is not good documentation for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Concept**

Loop through all the objects in the data and check if the id is found in result array. If not found then push it into the result array; otherwise, skip it.

**Code**

```js
const data = [{
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-01',
  },
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-02',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-03',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
  {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
  {
    id: '12002812',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
  {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-08',
  },
];
let result = [];
let found;
data.forEach(d => {
  found = false;
  result.forEach(r => {
    if (!found && r.id === d.id) found = true;
  })
  if (!found) result.push(d);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If the ids are not in order this will not work be careful!

Answer (score 0):

You can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array into an object that stores only the first occurrence of every id and then extract the [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) from this object.

```js
const 
  data = [{ id: "10000844", text_id: "10000844-01" }, { id: "10000844", text_id: "10000844-02" }, { id: "12000844", text_id: "12000844-03" }, { id: "12000844", text_id: "12000844-07" }, { id: "12000814", text_id: "12000844-07" }, { id: "12002812", text_id: "12000844-07" }, { id: "12000814", text_id: "12000844-08" }],
  result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, d) => (!acc[d.id] ? { ...acc, [d.id]: d } : acc), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You may want to document how that one-liner works since it will be gibberish to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve you desire output.
we use `reduce` for changing in data and use `find` function to get current `id` is already in `prev` or not if `not` then we use `filter` function to filter out same `id` object and push only first.

```js
const data =[
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-01',
  },
  {
    id: '10000844',
    text_id: '10000844-02',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-03',
  },
  {
    id: '12000844',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
  {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
 {
    id: '12002812',
    text_id: '12000844-07',
  },
   {
    id: '12000814',
    text_id: '12000844-08',
  },
]

const newData = data.reduce((prev, curr, index, arr) => {
  const find = prev.find(p => p.id === curr.id);
  if (!find) {
    const filter = arr.filter(f => f.id === curr.id);
    if (filter.length >= 1) {
      prev.push(filter[0])
    }
  }
  return prev;
}, [])

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers are already correct.

**THIS ANSWER IS ONLY IF YOU ARE USING LODASH**

You can use [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy).

This will return a duplicate-free version of an array where the first occurrence is the one that will be kept:

So in your case, something like

```
import uniqBy from 'lodash/uniqBy';

// dataFromAPI is your sample data
const unqiueArray = uniqBy(dataFromAPI, 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes [a simple loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) is the way forward.

1. Create a temporary object
2. Iterate over the data adding objects to that object if their key can't be found.
3. Get the values of the output object

```js
const data=[{id:"10000844",text_id:"10000844-01"},{id:"10000844",text_id:"10000844-02"},{id:"12000844",text_id:"12000844-03"},{id:"12000844",text_id:"12000844-07"},{id:"12000814",text_id:"12000844-07"},{id:"12002812",text_id:"12000844-07"},{id:"12000814",text_id:"12000844-08"}];

// Initialise the output object
const out = {};

// Loop over the array of objects
for (const obj of data) {

  // For each object destructure the id from the rest
  // of its properties 
  const { id, ...rest } = obj;

  // If there is no property on the output
  // object with that key create it by adding
  // an object composed of the id and the other
  // object properties to it
  out[id] ??= { id, ...rest };
}

// Now return an array of
// the output object's values
console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)